# child of the component "this" value and how do I get to parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

child of the component "this" value and how do I get to parent component?

ex:

```
class AComponent extends Component{
 static getThis(){
   return this;
  }
}




class MainComp extends Component{

componentDidMoud(){
  console.log(AComponent.getThis());
 }
}
```

in this way, how do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't get the parent component from a child component. If you need to do something (ie affect parent component state), then pass a function from the parent to the child as a prop to do it. If you need to read something, then pass the relevant data from parent to child as a prop to read it.

Comment: How can what be done? I suggest reading through https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html which demonstrates both passing functions and data through props

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props down to children, whether it be a simple primitive value for the child component to use, or a function that can be used by the child component to change the state of the parent component. Here's a simple example.

**ParentComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      someState: true
    };

    this.someFunction = this.someFunction.bind(this);
  }

  someFunction() {
    this.setState({
      someState: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent aFunc={this.someFunction} aString="someValue"/>
    );
  }
}
```

**ChildComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.aString}>
        <button onClick={this.props.aFunc}>
          Some text
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```